# Highlight selected row of table in SAP UI5

Tags: sapui5

I am using sap.m.table with mode "SingleSelectLeft" and with Aggregation ColumnListItem of type "Navigation".

On clicking of any of the items from the table, I want to show another page in split-app(detail page). I have put the routing code in the press event of ColumnListItem but this is leading to an issue as :

The selected item goes off(not appearing selected) when I click on the detail page.

Here is the snippet I am working with:

```
            <Table inset="false" noDataText="{i18n>noDataMasterTable}" mode="SingleSelectLeft" selectionChange="onLineItemSelected" id="s2-table"
                updateFinished="onListUpdateFinished" items="{mainService>/Bp}" busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/lineItemTableDelay}"
                itemPress="handleMasterPress" width="100%"  >
                <headerToolbar>
                    <OverflowToolbar>


                        <SearchField id="s2-searchfield-search" tooltip="{i18n>searchToolTip}" liveChange="onSearch" width="auto"></SearchField>
                        <Button id="s2-table-activate" text="Activate" press="handleActivateBusinessPurpose" enabled="false"/>
                        <Button id="s2-table-delete" text="{i18n>delete}" press="handleDelete" enabled="false"/>
                        <Button id="s2-table-add" icon="sap-icon://add" press="handleCreatePress" tooltip="{i18n>addToolTip}"/>
                    </OverflowToolbar>
                </headerToolbar>
                <columns>
                    <Column >
                        <Text text="{i18n>Name}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="{i18n>ApplicationGroupName}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                        <Text text="{i18n>DataSubjectType}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                        <Text text="{i18n>LegalEntity}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                        <Text text="{i18n>Status}"/>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="handleMasterPress">
                    <!--<ColumnListItem >-->
                        <cells>
                            <ObjectIdentifier title="{mainService>BusinessPurposeName}"/>
                            <ObjectIdentifier text="{mainService>ApplicationGroupName}"/>
                            <ObjectIdentifier text="{mainService>DataSubjectType}"/>
                            <ObjectIdentifier text="{mainService>LegalEntityValue}"/>
                            <ObjectStatus text="{path:'mainService>Status', formatter:'.formatPurposeStatus'}"
                                state="{path:'mainService>Status', formatter:'.formatStatusColor'}"/>
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
```

Please let me know how can I show the selected item highlighted in the table.

Comment: Can you be more specific about the issue? I'm not sure about the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you are firing 2 event on pressing and handling them with the same function. So, delete `itemPress="handleMasterPress"` or use another funtion.

Then, handleMasterPress() will be executed by the `<ColumnListItem type="Navigation" press="handleMasterPress">`

So in the handler, get the source from the event object and pass it to the table in the setSelectedItem() function

```
handleMasterPress: function(oEvent){
    var oColumnListItem = oEvent.getSource();
    var oTable = oColumnListItem.getParent();
    oTable.setSelectedItem(oColumnListItem);
}
```

Here a working snippet

```js
// define a new (simple) Controller type
   sap.ui.controller("my.own.controller", {
    
    handleMasterPress: function(oEvent){
      var oColumnListItem = oEvent.getSource();
      console.log(oColumnListItem.getMetadata())
      var oTable = oColumnListItem.getParent();
      oTable.setSelectedItem(oColumnListItem);
    }
   });

   // instantiate the View
   var myView = sap.ui.xmlview({viewContent:jQuery('#view1').html()}); // accessing the HTML inside the script tag above

   // create some dummy JSON data
   var data = {
      WaybillsPlaces: [{
        CoNumber: "Item 1",
      },{
        CoNumber: "Item 2",
      },{
        CoNumber: "Item 3",
      }]
    };
   
   // create a Model and assign it to the View
   var oModel = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel();
   oModel.setData(data);
   myView.setModel(oModel, "mainService");
   
   
   // put the View onto the screen
   myView.placeAt('content');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>MVC with XmlView</title>

  <!-- Load UI5, select "blue crystal" theme and the "sap.m" control library -->
  <script id='sap-ui-bootstrap'
    src='https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js'
   data-sap-ui-theme='sap_bluecrystal'
   data-sap-ui-libs='sap.m'
   data-sap-ui-xx-bindingSyntax='complex'></script>


  <!-- DEFINE RE-USE COMPONENTS - NORMALLY DONE IN SEPARATE FILES -->

  <!-- define a new (simple) View type as an XmlView
   - using data binding for the Button text
   - binding a controller method to the Button's "press" event
   - also mixing in some plain HTML
   note: typically this would be a standalone file -->

  <script id="view1" type="sapui5/xmlview">
      <mvc:View
    controllerName="my.own.controller"
    xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc"
    xmlns="sap.m">
      <Panel headerText="Table Panel">
        <Table inset="false" noDataText="{i18n>noDataMasterTable}" mode="SingleSelectLeft" selectionChange="onLineItemSelected" id="s2-table"
                updateFinished="onListUpdateFinished" items="{mainService>/WaybillsPlaces}" busyIndicatorDelay="{detailView>/lineItemTableDelay}"
                 width="100%"  >
                <headerToolbar>
                    <OverflowToolbar>


                        <SearchField id="s2-searchfield-search" tooltip="{i18n>searchToolTip}" liveChange="onSearch" width="auto"></SearchField>
                        <Button id="s2-table-activate" text="Activate" press="handleActivateBusinessPurpose" enabled="false"/>
                        <Button id="s2-table-delete" text="{i18n>delete}" press="handleDelete" enabled="false"/>
                        <Button id="s2-table-add" icon="sap-icon://add" press="handleCreatePress" tooltip="{i18n>addToolTip}"/>
                    </OverflowToolbar>
                </headerToolbar>
                <columns>
                    <Column >
                        <Text text="{i18n>Name}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column>
                        <Text text="{i18n>ApplicationGroupName}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                        <Text text="{i18n>DataSubjectType}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                        <Text text="{i18n>LegalEntity}"/>
                    </Column>
                    <Column demandPopin="true" minScreenWidth="Tablet">
                        <Text text="{i18n>Status}"/>
                    </Column>
                </columns>
                <items>
                    <ColumnListItem type="Active" press="handleMasterPress">
                    <!--<ColumnListItem >-->
                        <cells>
                            <ObjectIdentifier title="{mainService>CoNumber}"/>
                            <ObjectIdentifier text="{mainService>CoNumber}"/>
                            <ObjectIdentifier text="{mainService>CoNumber}"/>
                            <ObjectIdentifier text="{mainService>CoNumber}"/>
                            <ObjectStatus text="{path:'mainService>Status', formatter:'.formatPurposeStatus'}"
                                state="{path:'mainService>Status', formatter:'.formatStatusColor'}"/>
                        </cells>
                    </ColumnListItem>
                </items>
            </Table>
        </Panel>
   </mvc:View>
 </script>
 
 </head>
 <body id='content' class='sapUiBody'>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks.
This was helpful.

However I would like to know : is there a way(property) to handle this in the view itself.
As in this approach : I am setting the selection of the item on the controller after and event from the view where the item is selected,

Comment: only if you use table mode = "SingleSelectMaster" instead of "SingleSelectLeft"

Comment: "SingleSelectLeft" is meant for selection using the radio button, leaving row click for other action, like Navigation for example

Answer (score -1):

Add the following attribute to the items element within the Table element:

```
items="{
          path: '{mainService>/Bp}',
          type : 'sap.m.ListType.Active'
       }"
```

Refer

```
sap.m.ListType.Active
```

Indicates that the item is clickable via active feedback when item is pressed.

Source: https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ListType/overview

Comment: this solution does not help. The listtype is applicable to the items(aggregation) of the list and not to the list.